# How do I get the CVS plugin working in Eclipse 2021-09?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cvs

I have an Eclipse 2021-09 install on a RHEL8 machine without Internet access.

Therefore I have downloaded the CVS jar `org.eclipse.cvs_1.4.1900.v20210906-0500.jar` on an other machine and then copied it into the `dropins` directory of my RHEL8 Eclipse install. After this I started the Eclipse IDE and now I can see that CVS plugin in Eclipse's list of plugins.

So far so good. But when I try to import a CVS project (via **File** > **Import**) I cannot see an CVS import option. Nowhere else I can see anything about the CVS plugin either.

How do I get the CVS plugin working in Eclipse 2021-09?

---

More Details:

Eclipse writes the follwoing messages to stdout/stderr:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/halloleo/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.16.1.20210603-1006.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
```

Comment: Anything in the error log? With which Java version do you run Eclipse?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, @howlger. Eclipse output added to question. Plus I don't use a special Java version: I just extracted the Eclipse archive and run the Eclipse executable in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plug-in on its own only contains a small part of the CVS code. The CVS feature.xml for 2021-09 contains:

```xml
  <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.cvs"
         download-size="30"
         install-size="40"
         version="1.4.1900.v20210906-0500"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.team.cvs.core"
         download-size="577"
         install-size="1343"
         version="3.5.0.v20210511-0556"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh2"
         download-size="30"
         install-size="57"
         version="3.4.0.v20210426-0837"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui"
         download-size="1527"
         install-size="3495"
         version="3.5.0.v20210426-0843"
         unpack="false"/>
```

So you need all those plug-ins.

Comment: Makes sense. Will try to download the other jars and see whether it works then. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that was it. CVS import now works. Thanks heaps!